# Literal partial with Mustache Php / Js?

Tags: javascript, php, mustache, template-engine

I'm using [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) to have the same templates on PHP side and on Javascript side, like this:

```
{{> myTemplate}}

<script id="myTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    {{> myTemplate}}
</script>
```

Problem: on page load, the partial "myTemplate" contained between the two "script" tags is changed by the data from my PHP. I need it unchanged in order to use it with my javascript.

Is there a way to do that please?

## Edit:

I found a solution : [Chevron.js](https://github.com/surdu/jquery-chevron) (a jQuery plugin) in addition to Mustache. I did something like this:

#### html:

```
<head>
    <link href="templates/myTemplate.mustache" rel="template" id="myTemplate" />
</head>
```

#### javascript:

```
$("#myTemplate").Chevron('render', data, function (html) {
    // do something with 'html'
});
```

Comment: yes mustache uses constant template delimiters, i suggest sth like [Contemplate](https://github.com/foo123/Contemplate) (author), which has support for custom delimiters (thus able to pass client-side template inside server-side template) and much more

Answer (score 0):

With [Contemplate](https://github.com/foo123/Contemplate) you could do sth like the following:

```
<% %>
<!-- server-side template -->
<% $server_data %>
<script id="myTemplate" type="x-contemplate">{% %}
     <!-- client-side template -->    
      {% $client_data %}
</script>
```

Each template defines its own delimiters, in a *modular* way, thus any template combination and nesting, eg have a server-side template include a client-side template, is handled optimaly (see related issue, https://github.com/foo123/Contemplate/issues/5)